# Creating a view from multiple content types where one is optional

Tags: views

Is it possible to display multiple content types within a view that may or may not have a related secondary content type?

I have two content types (A - which contains a title and body field, and B - which contains a title and body field). In this view, content type A will always exist - and I would like to have any related B content types display underneath the appropriate object. It is possible that no content B types will exist for that title, so if that's the case it can move on and display the next content A type info:

(A) Title = New York, body = "Something"
(A) Title = Ohio, body = "Something"
     (B) Title = Ohio, body = "An interesting tidbit about Ohio"
(A) Title = Virginia, body = "Something"
...etc...

Any idea how I may go about accomplishing this? I have heard about a References module to explore, but it seems like that would only pull data where that relationship exists, right? And that in my above example, although I would be anticipating three states in my view, references would only show me the Ohio one because that's the only one that also contains a content B type.

Is that correct? Or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: How do you relate Type B to Type A? Do you use a refernce field? What is the cardinality of the reference (0-1, 0-many)?

Comment: That's part of my question, I guess. Right now, nothing is set up. Content B would have a 0-1 relationship to Content A. Any idea how I would set up a reference like that?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, and create an entity reference field on your Content Type B. Configure the field to reference Target Type *Content* and Target bundle *Type A*. Lets call the field ref_to_a.

Set up a view of Content Type A as a table of fields. Add the *Title* and *Body* fields. Then under *Advanced* add a Relationship. Use *Entity Reference: Referencing Entity* and choose **Content referencing Content from field_ref_to_a** Do not set the relationship as required, as you do not want to exclude the Type A records which do not have a Type B referencing them.

Now add a *Content:Body* field to your view, and configure it to use the relationship you have just created.

This should give you a view which will look like:

```
New York    Something
Ohio        Something   Interesting tidbit
Virginia    Something
```

Adjust your formatting as required, and good luck.